# LCD Module Datasheet Or Other Info

Tags: lcd, datasheet

So I came across this LCD module the other day. The only obvious writing on it is SOLOMON. After typing in every number I could find on it I finally came across this mention online: http://nutsvolts.texterity.com/nutsvolts/200503/?pg=35#pg35 See the lower left on page 35, its the 16x4 LCD.

So apparently it is a Solomon Goldentek #LM1112SYL, but a google search for that turns up almost nothing. Trying to find the product on the goldentek website is a no go either. Anyone know where I can find a datasheet or anything that would tell me how to interface with this guy?

I can't even tell where the power is supposed to be connected...
[image]

Comment: It's a 2005 magazine, so it's possible that it's been discontinued...

Comment: -1 because not only doesn't your link go to a nice clear page for a LCD, it tried to hijack my browser such that ALT-Left didn't return here.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but shouldn't I still be able to find a datasheet somewhere? It's not like it's been discontinued since before the internet...

Comment: @OlinLathrop Really? When I click it using both firefox and chrome, it takes me to an online catalog. It's one of those digital scan editions of a magazine so there's no single link to the LCD. Not sure what I can do about that.

Comment: Based on the form factor (size, mounting hole location, pin location) I would guess that it is HD44780 compatible.  The fact that it is a 16x4 display drives that thought home.

Comment: I second (grumpy) Olin's comment: why didn't you take a screenshot of the page and show the bottom left part here?

Comment: @Johan.A I didn't realize people still used browsers which don't support flash. That's been pretty heavily adopted for like 15 years?

Comment: @NickHalden: don't be condescending. My browser supports Flash. But it's silly to have to go into a full magazine if you only need a 20 cm^2 image of a single page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely to be the [GC1604N0](http://www.goldentek.com.tw/index.php?_Page=product&mode=show&cid=14&pid=79&_lang=E), which is the only textual 16x4 display now available by Goldentek.

Note that the part number you found seems not to be consistent with the usual coding of the manufacturer, as they use GC* instead of LM*.

Here there is their [coding standard](http://www.goldentek.com.tw/index.php?_Page=product&cid=19&_lang=E), which seems not including the 'LM*' code.

For understanding the interface you can try to use the block scheme, in which the pins should be displayed in the right order. The problem is that the board has 16 pins while the scheme shows only 14 lines: trying to find where is the supply turning the backlight on may be a way to go.

Comment: Hm, good find. Unfortunately, that 'datasheet' is definitely for a GC part and I definitely have an LM part so it's not necessarily accurate. Assuming it is equivalent though, am I missing something or did they leave out labeling the pins?

Comment: @JGord where did you find the 'LM' code? Anyway the dimensions seem to be the same

Comment: Adding a picture to my question. Based on the measurements they seem to be the same, but there's no useful interface information.

Comment: You can see from the silkscreen that pins 15 and 16 are for the backlight.  There's even solder-bridge jumpers to set anode and cathode of the backlight.  I suspect pins 1-14 are the standard LCD character display pinout.

Comment: @markrages this means that there is no relation between the pinout and the part I linked?

Answer (score 3):

I purchased one of these displays a few years ago from All Electronics. They no longer sell them but they do have the datasheet available at http://www.allelectronics.com/mas_assets/spec/LCD-108.pdf. I recently pulled mine out and hooked it up a Raspberry Pi to display some text. It works well but I have a problem with the backlight. The backlight seems to be powered by VDD so it is always on. I would like the ability to turn the backlight off so if anyone has any idea how to turn it on and off, please reply.

Comment: While the datasheet you link is valid, if you have further questions, please add them as a separate question. Stack exchange (Including this site, Electrical Engineering) is not a traditional forum. There is really no concept of "replies" in a question.